# Provide Control Name via String

Tags: vba, ms-access

"Me.strLblName.FontBold = True" does not work.  I have tried Me.& strLblName &.FontBold = True along with many others.  Is this a syntax thing or do I need another method?

```
**Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim ctl As Control, intUsage As Integer, strCtlName As String, strLblName As String
For Each ctl In Me.Form.Controls
    Select Case ctl.ControlType
        Case acCommandButton
            intUsage = DLookup("process_usage", "tbl_db_stats", "cbtn_name = '" & ctl.Name & "'")
            Debug.Print ctl.ControlType, ctl.Name, intUsage
            strLblName = "lbl_" & Right(ctl.Name, Len(ctl.Name) - 5)
            If intUsage < 10 Then
                Stop
                'CHANGE LABEL TEXT TO BOLD
                Me.strLblName.FontBold = True
            End If
    End Select
Next ctl
End Sub**
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Controls(strLblName).FontBold = True
```

Comment: Could you explain why your solution answers the question?

Comment: Not trying to be smart but I just do not understand how that is not obvious. Me.strLblName.FontBold = True is replaced with Controls(strLblName).FontBold = True

Comment: I see that it's right...but probably ought to have some safety...like making sure Controls(strLbName) actually returned something before setting a property on it.